# MoveToElement and Click() in selenium webdriver is not working for me in C#

Tags: c#, webdriver

I have a toggle button that becomes active/visible only when MoseOver on it. I need to click on it and select the options from the drop down menu. This is the code and my attempts to automate bellow:

```
<div class="project active">
<div class="header">
  <span class="badge badge-info">0 sites</span>
     <a class="description" data-original-title="auto test" rel="tooltip" href="#">
  <div class="modified">Modified: 2013-01-30 18:46:08Z</div>
  <div class="btn-group">
     <a class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-target="#projectConfigMenu_62">
       <i class="icon-cog"></i>
       <span class="caret"></span>
     </a>
  <ul id="projectConfigMenu_62" class="dropdown-menu" style="top: 297.867px; left: 194px; display: none;">
</div>
```

Here is how I am trying to solve it, I can see the button, but it wouldn't click on it:

```
IWebElement active_element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@class='project active']"));            
IWebElement button = active_element.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@class='btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle']"));             
IWebElement buttondrop = button.FindElement(By.XPath("//i[@class='icon-cog']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);             
builder.MoveToElement(active_element).MoveToElement(buttondrop).Click().Build().Perform();
```

Comment: Why have you felt the need to post this question 7 times in the past few weeks?

Comment: I am looking for a solution (and so far cannot find !!) for my script  issue and hope that someone who is more knowledgeable and experienced than myself - will help me out, I thought that was the purpose of that site, is that wrong ? Do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: @Aluchia Yes, that's the purpose of this site. However, asking the **exact same question** multiple times, just because you didn't get an answer, or the answer you want, is not an efficient use of StackOverflow. Furthermore, when dealing with things like elements that appear on mouse hover, showing the HTML only is usually not sufficient to debug or test the problem. Those scenarios usually involve some combination of JavaScript and CSS, without which, it's nearly impossible to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok, to all with the same issues - FF17 and FF18 are not supppted by v2.28 or v2.2.9 webdrivers, and that is why I am having problems fixing my script. (thanks to the folks from SeleniumQA !!), at least I know there is nothing wrong with my code.  (and to answer the above question to Jim - I don't have any JavaScript or CSS to provide, there isn't any).